# How to use groupby with integer values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a data frame with one column and 793 entries with following distribution

```
df.groupby([‘OK2Use`]).size()
OK2Use
0    305
1    150
2    338
dtype: int64
```

How do I access individual sums namely 305, 150 and 338?. I see examples like grouped_df.get_group('value') when values are string but that doesn't seem to work with integers

Answer (score 1):

You can access the individual values using the index, which represents the integer you are counting. I mocked up an example, so the numbers are different, but this should be what you need.

`grouped_df = df.groupby(['OK2Use']).size()`

```
grouped_df
Out[9]: 
OK2Use
0     9
1    11
2    13
dtype: int64

grouped_df[1]
Out[10]: 11

grouped_df[2]
Out[11]: 13

grouped_df[0]
Out[12]: 9
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark this answered if you feel it adequately answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using index to access the output.
For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c']})
df.groupby('col').size()
col
c    4
d    2
e    1
dtype: int64
df.groupby('col').size()['c']
4
```